# Waiting for event to be handled with AutoResetEvent

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want to stop performing my code till website will be loaded(I use Windows.Forms.WebBrowser). I read that I should use AutoResetEvent, but I don't use any class related to threading before. I write this code, but it only freeze my program, how fix it?

```
var evt = new AutoResetEvent(false);
webBrowser.DocumentCompleted += (sender1, e1) =>
{
    if (webBrowser.ReadyState == WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
    {
        evt.Set();
    }

};
webBrowser.Navigate("https://www.google.com/");
evt.WaitOne();      //wait to evt.Set() call
//...
//further code
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Threads totally freezes the GUI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10423966/threads-totally-freezes-the-gui)

Comment: Why not just move the code after WaitOne into the DocumentCompleted event handler??

Comment: The DocumentCompleted event can only fire when your UI thread is idle.  It is not idle, it is stuck on the WaitOne() call.  This is called deadlock.  *Never* block the UI thread.  Simply move the code after the WaitOne call into your DocumentCompleted event handler.

Answer (score 1):

You can utilize async/await and can use *TaskCompletionSource* instead of *AutoResetEvent*

```
TaskCompletionSource<object> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
webBrowser.DocumentCompleted += (sender1, e1) => tcs.TrySetResult(null);
webBrowser.Navigate("https://www.google.com/");
await tcs.Task;
```

Answer (score 0):

I used Invoke. But the Invoke was in another Thread, in this case in Elapsed of a System.Timers.Timer

```
MethodInvoker invoke = delegate ()
{
     webBrowser1.Navigate(url);
};
this.Invoke(invoke);
this.autoresetevent.WaitOne();
```

and

```
void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
     this.autoresetevent.Set();
}
```