# How to make AutoResetEvent wait handle be triggered on Test Method?

Tags: c#, multithreading, visual-studio, unit-testing

In working in a automated test (MSTest) in C# where the test method calls a mehtod from an external library and then it must wait until an event is triggered, signaling the operation is completed.

I am trying to use the approach described in [this article](https://www.devjoy.com/blog/unit-testing-events-and-callbacks-in-csharp/):

```
[Test]
public void TestEventualEventTimesOut() {
  AutoResetEvent _autoResetEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
  var actual = string.Empty;

  var aClass = new AClass();
  aClass.SomethingHappened += (_, s) => { actual = s; _autoResetEvent.Set(); };

  aClass.DoSomethingThatFiresAnEventEventually("A");


  Assert.IsFalse(_autoResetEvent.WaitOne());
  Assert.AreEqual("", actual);
}
```

The problem is the "SomethingHappened" is never fired.

I verified the event is properly fired if this method is called from a Windows Forms application instead of test method, for example.

The "DoSomethingThatFiresAnEventEventually" method internally also call some methods and later some events will be fired where finally the SomethingHappened event will be triggered.

I also tried to use the TaskCompletionSource strategy from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36252882/waiting-for-event-to-be-handled-with-autoresetevent), but no change in the behavior.

I am trying to understand why this is not working in my test method? Any ideas hot to debug this?

EDIT: This is the code from the TaskCompletionSource approach:

```
TaskCompletionSource<object> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();

        myObject.RefreshReady += (_, s) =>
        {
            //never hit
            tcs.TrySetResult(null);
        };

        myObject.Refresh();

        await tcs.Task;

        Assert.Fail(); //never hit
```

EDIT2: Even after testing the approach suggested to use a separate thread, this is still no working.

I tried to use these approaches (even if not necessary) in the WindowsForms project (not in the unit test project) to make sure there is no assembly missing or something with how the tests are executed.

So I got the same behavior. I suspect something in the main thread is blocking the autoresetevent to be set properly.

--
Igor

Comment: It makes no sense that i work within the code of `Form` unless that class is a `Control` or a `UserControl`. This code works perfectly fine as is. You do know that if your event launches at 3 second the `AutoResetEvent` reset before it actually triggers ?

Comment: The word 'eventually' makes me wonder. Should you add `_autoResetEvent.WaitOne()` before `sw.Stop()`?

Comment: I would have gone with the task completion strategy. calling the target member and then awaiting the event to fire. Can you show what you did for that approach?

Comment: You should also be explicit about what the target class is and does. If a UI concern you may have issues when running in a unit test which is not UI aware

Comment: Are you sure all the dependencies that are available when running are available when unit testing?

Comment: I suspect in your test setup you are not subscribing to the 'inner' events, that's why your event handler is not being hit. I would suggest to mock (stub) the inner dependencies, in order to lose this complexity in your unit tests.

Answer (score 0):

I personally recommend to not use the AWAIT expression while manipulating some object events, events are always fired from the main_thread, so if you are in a wait chain process the event will never be able to notify the main thread.

One approach you can do is creating a new thread for the intended operation and it won't lock the main thread.